# Can I detect change in text fields in SWT?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have a couple of SWT widgets. I am trying to create an action if there is any modification in any of the fields present.

Example: If I change the name from the `Text` I should be able to identify it. I tried searching online for a solution but couldn't find a suitable one.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use [addModifyListener](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FText.html)

```
ModifyListener listener = new ModifyListener() {
    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
        // Handle event
    }
});

text1.addModifyListener(listener);
text2.addModifyListener(listener);
```