# How to hide an SWT composite so that it takes no space?

Tags: java, swt

I need to hide a composite (and all children inside). Just setting `setVisible(false)` will keep the space of the composite.

```
Composite outer = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);      
outer.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,false));
outer.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH) );

Composite compToHide = new MyComposite(outer, SWT.NONE);        
compToHide.setLayout(new GridLayout());
compToHide.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: Solution is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511442/eclipse-plugin-make-combo-to-handle-enter-key i.e. addListener()

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is some code that does what you want. I basically use `GridData#exclude` in combination with `Control#setVisible(boolean)` to hide/unhide the `Composite`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

    Button hideButton = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    hideButton.setText("Toggle");

    final Composite content = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, false));

    final GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    content.setLayoutData(data);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        new Label(content, SWT.NONE).setText("Label " + i);
    }

    hideButton.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            data.exclude = !data.exclude;
            content.setVisible(!data.exclude);
            content.getParent().pack();
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Before hiding:

[image]

After hiding:

[image]

Comment: the problem is with shell.pack(), I can't use it because it affects whole gui

Comment: @yuris Can you use `pack()` on the parent of the composite you are trying to hide? If so, look at my updated code. If not, you will have to manually decrease the size of the shell by the size of the hidden composite.

Comment: How about `content.getParent().layout(true, true)`?

Answer (score 6):

Define a GridData for your control and then after you do:
`control.setVisible(false)` do `gridData.exclude=true`

Comment: I like this idea! Thanks!