# How to reorder Tables

Tags: java, swt

I am learning to work with SWT.
I added two `Table`s to one `Composite` using:

```
    TabFolder tabFolder = new TabFolder(shell, SWT.NONE);
    tabFolder.setLayoutData(BorderLayout.CENTER);

    TabItem tbtmData = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
    tbtmData.setText("data");

    scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(tabFolder, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    tbtmData.setControl(scrolledComposite);
    scrolledComposite.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    scrolledComposite.setExpandVertical(true);

    tableComposite = new Composite(scrolledComposite, SWT.NONE);
    RowLayout rl_tableComposite = new RowLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL);
    tableComposite.setLayout(rl_tableComposite);

    table_2 = new Table(tableComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    table_2.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table_2.setLinesVisible(true);

    table_3 = new Table(tableComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    table_3.setLayoutData(new RowData(261, 45));
    table_3.setTopIndex(1);
    table_3.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table_3.setLinesVisible(true);



    scrolledComposite.setContent(tableComposite);
    scrolledComposite.setMinSize(tableComposite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));

    TabItem tbtmGraph = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
    tbtmGraph.setText("graph");

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
    tbtmGraph.setControl(canvas);
```

Now, in the window I see `table_2` in the left and `table_3` in the right. How to change the order in a runtime? Adding table_3 first is not an option in my case.

One more question. if i call `table.setSize(0, 0);` I don't see any changes in table appearance. I tried to call `table.redraw()` after that, but still, size of the table is not changing. where is my mistake?

Comment: What is a `table` is it another window?

Comment: well… table is SWT widget. It comes from org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;

Comment: @PauliusM What `Layout` are you using?

Comment: horizontal `RowLayout`. I updated question with more code.

Comment: @PauliusM Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call:

```
tableThree.moveAbove(tableTwo);
```

See the [javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.html#moveAbove%28org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control%29) for more detail.

As for your second question:

Why do you want to set the size to `0`? Doesn't [`Control#setVisible(false)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.html#setVisible%28boolean%29) do the trick?

Comment: yes, `tableThree.moveAbove(tableTwo)` works fine.
I want to set table size to zero, so other controls could occupy the space that was previous occupied by the table. Its not happening when I try to use `setVisible(false)`

Comment: @PauliusM This question has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17513270/1740724). In addition, you can simply `dispose()` the `Table` if you don't need it anymore.

Comment: I manage to achieve desirable behaviour of the `table`'s by using code in the link you provided. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @PauliusM No problem, alsways glad if I can help :)