# How to show/hide a text field based on the selection of a radio button?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I want to show/hide a text field based on the selection of a radio buttons inside a Wizard Page.

In the below page, there are 2 radio buttons. On selection of the first one, a text field will be displayed. While on the selection of the other radio button, the same text field must be hidden.

```
Button button= null;
Button button2= null;
private Text interfaceId = null;
Label labelText = null;

@Override
public void createControl(Composite parent) {
    page = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    setControl(page);
    setPageComplete(false);
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
    gridLayout.numColumns = 2;
    gridLayout.makeColumnsEqualWidth = false;
    page.setLayout(gridLayout);

    page.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

    Label label = new Label(page, SWT.NONE);
    label.setText("Service");

    button= new Button(page, SWT.RADIO);
    button.setSelection(false);
    button.addSelectionListener(new ButtonListener());

    Label label2 = new Label(page, SWT.NONE);
    label2.setText("Node");

    button2= new Button(page, SWT.RADIO);
    button2.setSelection(false);
    button2.addSelectionListener(new ButtonListener());

}
```

The Button Listener class -

```
     class ButtonListener extends SelectionAdapter {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

            if(interfaceR.getSelection()) {

                labelText = new Label(page, SWT.NONE);
                labelText .setText("Interface Id : ");


                interfaceId = new Text(page, SWT.BORDER);
                GridData interfaceIdGridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
                interfaceId.setLayoutData(interfaceIdGridData);
            } else {

            }



            // re-do layout 
            page.layout();
        }
    }
```

I am unable to make it work.

Comment: Create everything at the start and use `setVisible` and `GridData.exclude` to show/hide things - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17513270/2670892)

Comment: The question was edited in between your comment.

Comment: I don't see anything that changes my comment. Create everything at the start.