# How can we set group invisible and it should not occupy space also using SWT

Tags: java, swt

Hi Team I have three group in one composite like shown in first image. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e341A.jpg)

Now I want a view  where first and second group are invisible and second group shift left side like shown in second image. Can Anyone please help me on this. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0d27.jpg)

Comment: What layouts are you using? For `GridLayout` you can combine `GridData.exclude` and `Control.setVisible`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17513270/2670892)

Comment: @greg-449 I am using GridLayout only

Comment: So that answer I linked covered it - you use GridData with GridLayout, you can't do advanced GridLayout things without using GridData on the individual components

Comment: Hi Greg - it is working when I am opening for new view.. Suppose view is open and we update it and again open new view in that case it is not working

Comment: GridLayout/GridData with exclude works, I use it all the time. If you are having problems you will have to show us your code as a [mre] We can't possibly help with the minimal information you have given us.

Comment: Hi Greg- yes it is working.. Actually my question is wrong. I have a view that i want to bring on top but because of createPart Control method it is not working. I want to use postWindowOpen method but not sure how to use it

Comment: If you mean the window advisor postWindowOpen that is for the main window and is nothing to do views. Ask a new question describing your problem - "not working" tells us nothing.